# Дубли в мат вью на БД АренаДата

Tags: sql, база-данных, обработка-данных

Могут ли возникать дубли при пересчете материализованных представлений, построенных на Аренадате, связанные с особенностями СУБД?
(Сам скрипт при разовом ручном запуске дубли не создает)